# It seems to ignore the Async / Await

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

On a React page, I have a method called `goOut`. This method calls upon a Redux action > Node controller > Redux reducer. I can confirm that the correct data values are returned inside the Redux action, the controller method, and the reducer. However, nonetheless, at point `1` below inside the `goOut` method, it returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong / how could it return `undefined` if the the reducer is returning the correct values? It is as if the `await` inside the `goOut` method is not working...

React page:

```
import { go_payment } from "../../appRedux/actions/paymentAction";

<button onClick={this.goOut}>
    Button
</button>

async goOut(ev) {
    try {
        const data = { user: parseInt(this.state.userId, 10) };
        let result = await this.props.go_payment({data});

        console.log(result);
        // 1. RETURNS UNDEFINED. As if it tries to execute this line before it has finished the previous line.
    {
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {go_payment}, dispatch
    );
};
```

Redux Action:

```
export const go_payment = (data) => {
    let token = getAuthToken();
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios
            .post(`${url}/goController`, data, { headers: { Authorization: `${token}` } })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {

                    // console.log confirms correct data for res.data
                    return dispatch({ type: GO_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
            })
    }
}
```

Node controller method:

```
Returns the correct data in json format.
```

Reducer:

```
export default function paymentReducer(state = initial_state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GO_SUCCESS:

            // console.log confirms action.payload contains the correct data
            return { ...state, goData: action.payload, couponData: "" };
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; "go_payment" isn't async at all, and eventually returns the result of calling "dispatch", inside the "then" function, which happens at an arbitrary time in the future. What do you *think* should be happening?

Comment: I thought that because I have `await this.props.go_payment` it would first execute all of the code in `go_payment` before it continues with the line: `console.log(result)`. Is there a way to make that happen inside the React page, without changing the Redux Action?

Comment: Even if it *did* wait you're dispatching a redux action--the end result of that dispatch will *eventually* be an update to the redux store, but that it *also* asynchronous--the store won't contain the new data until (a) sometimes after the fetch completed, and (b) after the redux action completes.

Comment: I'd suggest maybe taking a step back re: asynch programming in general, and React/Redux since it has its own asynchronous aspects not handled by a simple "await"/"then". This is fundamental to JS, React, and Redux.

Comment: Ah, all right, I'm starting to understand. I guess that means it needs to be set up very differently. I think it's best to remove this question then? Or would you like to add an answer?

Comment: The *setup* is (probably) fine--the issue seems to be around understanding when and where data is available. That may mean there are gaps around what to do before new data is available.

Comment: Hey I also noticed you are defining data as an object like: 

const data = { user: 'something }

then you are passing it as a argumnet to the goPayment function as another object within an object

this.props.goPayment({data})

so when you are pulling the data in the function its going to look like 
{ data: { user: 'something' } }

it also depends what the endpoint is requiring as a payload 

this is just something to be aware of in future but also this wont solve your problem as the comments mentioned above state that the way to use actions is not being done correctly